# How do I put a localStorage var inside my ng-show ? (Angular JS/Firebase)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

---

**SITUATION:**

When I load a page and didn't log in yet, everything works fine and I only see `Login` and `Register` in my nav as should be the case.

But when I log in and I load any page, the nav will stay for about 0.5 to 1 seconds in a strange state where `"Register", "Log in", "Profile" and "Log out"` all appear at the same time.

Then the nav appears as it should: showing only `"Profile" and "Log out"`.

**EDIT:** `ng-cloack` fixed this, but profile and log out don't appear when I log in.

---

**CODE:**

header.ejs

```html
<html ng-app = "app">
        <div ng-controller="ctrlHead">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ng-show="!authenticated"><a href="/users/register">JOIN</a></li>
                <li ng-show="!authenticated"><a href="/users/login">Login</a></li>
                <li ng-show="authenticated"><a href="/users/profile">ME</a></li>
                <li ng-show="authenticated" onclick="signOut();"><a>Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
```

---

**QUESTION:**

How do I input a localStorage var inside my ng-show ?

P.S.: header.ejs is an EJS partial that is loaded on all pages.

---

**WHAT I TRIED:**

This works but reloads the nav at each page, causing flickering.

```
app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
    return $firebaseAuth();
  }
]);

app.controller("ctrlHead", ["$scope", "Auth", "$window",
  function($scope, Auth, $window) {
    $scope.auth = Auth;

    $scope.auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {
        if (firebaseUser) {
            setAppCookie();
        }
        $scope.authenticated = firebaseUser;
    });
  }
]);
```

My try using `localStorage`:

```
app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
    return $firebaseAuth();
  }
]);

app.controller("ctrlHead", ["$scope", "Auth", "$window",
  function($scope, Auth, $window) {
    $scope.authenticated = $window.localStorage.getItem("authenticated");
    $scope.auth = Auth;

    $scope.auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {
        if (firebaseUser) {
            setAppCookie();
        }
        $window.localStorage.setItem("authenticated", firebaseUser);
        $scope.authenticated = $window.localStorage.getItem("authenticated");
    });
  }
]);
```

And now with `ngCookies`... Did not work :/ The nav is stuck in logged in mode regardless of auth state.

```
app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
    return $firebaseAuth();
  }
]);

app.controller("ctrlHead", ["$scope", "Auth", "$cookies",
  function($scope, Auth, $cookies) {

    $scope.auth = Auth;

    $scope.auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {

        if (firebaseUser) {
            setAppCookie();
            $cookies.put('authenticated', firebaseUser);
            $scope.authenticated = $cookies.get('authenticated');
        } else {
            $cookies.put('authenticated', firebaseUser);
            $scope.authenticated = $cookies.get('authenticated');
        }
    });

  }
]);
```

---

**EDIT:** I am now using angularfire and it works fine except for one thing, I need to store the authstate in localStorage. I have been trying with ng-storage and $window.localSorage but it didn't work...

Comment: Is this live somewhere?

Comment: @SergChernata Sadly not :/

Comment: Could you make a fiddle? I could help you debug but without a live example it's really tough to tell what's going on.

Comment: @SergChernata hmmm, let me see how I can do that. I need to authenticate you somehow.

Comment: I have to say, I can't reproduce the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/wyus5d6a/

Comment: @SergChernata Weird it works fine in the jsfiddle...  https://jsfiddle.net/1cmwo9Lr/1/

Comment: @SergChernata Let me try to reproduce it in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134116/discussion-between-serg-chernata-and-coder1000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the angular `ng-cloak` directive in order to prevent the AngularJS html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading.

[ngCloak documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

```html
<html ng-app="app" ng-cloak>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li ng-show="!authenticated"><a href="/users/register">JOIN</a></li>
            <li ng-show="!authenticated"><a href="/users/login">Login</a></li>
            <li ng-show="authenticated"><a href="/users/profile">ME</a></li>
            <li ng-show="authenticated" onclick="signOut();"><a>Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
</html>
```

You should use the `$window` service to access variable created outside of the scope of your controller. On top of that, you should not create the (almost) same controller twice.

[$window documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)

Using something like that (not tested):

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    console.log("CURRENT USER:" + firebase.auth().currentUser);
    app.controller('ctrl', function($rootScope, $window) {
        $scope.authenticated = $window.user != null;
        setAppCookie();
        // Compile the whole <body> with the angular module named "app"
        angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
    });
});
```

For local storage, you just need to use the regular one:

```js
//Set item
localStorage.setItem("authenticated", JSON.stringify(firebaseUser));

//Get item
$scope.authenticated = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authenticated"));
```

Comment: Perfect ! Now could you please tell me why ME and Log out never appear ? What have I done wrong ?

Comment: @Coder1000 Updated my answer

Comment: This will not work since user is an Object, not a boolean.

Comment: @Coder1000 Updated

Comment: Did not work. But you mentioned I shouldn't have twice the same controller: let me update my question.

Comment: Question edited. Please have a look again: I posted the full code.

Comment: @Coder1000 Updated answer about localStorage

Answer (score -1):

You have declared the $rootScope, but I don't see where you injected..

Remember all dependencies have to be injected through the $inject dependency..

```
    Var app = controller('mycontroller', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
}]);
```