# Error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['firebase', 'ngCookies']);

app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
    return $firebaseAuth();
  }
]);

app.controller("ctrlHead", ["$scope", "Auth", "$cookies",
  function($scope, Auth, $cookies) {

    if ($cookies.get('authenticated') == null) {
        $cookies.put('authenticated', false);
    }

    $scope.auth = Auth;

    $scope.auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {

        if (firebaseUser) {
            setAppCookie();
            $cookies.put('authenticated', true);
        } else {
            $cookies.put('authenticated', false);
        }

    });
    $scope.authenticated =  $cookies.get('authenticated');  
  }
]);
```

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…0Lc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A21%3A332)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no typo, make sure you have added the firebase and angular-cookies references correctly in the following order,

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular
  .module('testApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'firebase'
  ])
 app.constant('FIREBASE_URL', 'https://testapp1000.firebaseio.com/')
   
app.controller("ctrlHead", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
   $scope.message = "angular firebase and cookies";
    }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.2" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="ctrlHead">
   <h1>{{message}}</h1>
    
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I thought they were part of angular by default ?

Comment: @Coder1000 No they are not, those are depdencies you need to inject

Comment: @Coder1000 ok no problem! i have added a demo

Comment: Great thx ! Btw, you seem experienced in angular.js Could you please have a look at my question here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811343/why-is-ng-show-not-working-angular-js-firebase